# Is it possible to generate a checksum (md5 ) a string in a shell?

Tags: bash, shell, md5, checksum

I would like to have a unique ID for filenames so I can iterate over the IDs and compare the checksums of the files?
Is it possible to have a checksum for the name of the file so I can have a unique ID per filename?
I would welcome other ideas.

Comment: If you want unique filenames you could try mktemp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it what you want?

Plain string:

```
serce@unit:~$ echo "Hello, checksum!" | md5sum
9f898618b071286a14d1937f9db13b8f  -
```

And file content:

```
serce@unit:~$ md5sum agent.yml
3ed53c48f073bd321339cd6a4c716c17  -
```

Comment: The file content case should work with a simple mdsum agent.yml, you dont need to use the cat

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible using `md5sum` and `basename $0` gives the name of current file

Assuming I have the script as below named `md5Gen.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

mdf5string=$(basename "$0" | md5sum )
echo -e `basename "$0"` $mdf5string
```

Running the script would give me

```
md5Gen.sh 911949bd2ab8467162e27c1b6b5633c0 -
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to obtain the MD5 of an string:

```
$ printf '%s' "This-Filename" | md5sum
dd829ba5a7ba7bdf7a391f2e0bd7cd1f  -
```

It is important to understand that there is no newline at the end of the printed string. An equivalent in bash would be to use `echo -n`:

```
$ echo -n "This-Filename" | md5sum
dd829ba5a7ba7bdf7a391f2e0bd7cd1f  -
```

The `-n` (valid in bash) is important because otherwise your hash would change with the inclusion of a newline that is not part of the text:

```
$ echo "This-Filename" | md5sum
7ccba9dffa4baf9ca0e56c078aa09a07  -
```

That also apply to file contents:

```
$ echo -n "This-Filename" > infile
$ md5sum infile
dd829ba5a7ba7bdf7a391f2e0bd7cd1f  infile

$ echo "This-Filename" > infile
$ md5sum infile
7ccba9dffa4baf9ca0e56c078aa09a07  infile
```